# How to auto send SMS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, sms

I thought this was impossible (without the user touching the "Send" button).
But, it seems that the [Auto SMS](http://itunes.apple.com/ke/app/auto-sms/id448969521?mt=8) application is able to schedule SMS to be sent without user interaction. How does it do that?
Note: this app doesn't use a server, I tested it off network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone) The only way to send a SMS using public APIs without user interaction is to use the MFMessageComposeViewController. As mentioned in the documentation, it requires the user choosing to send or cancel the message. You should test again disabling WiFi and data services, or just look up the sender on the recipient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send SMS from an iPhone app without opening the SMS interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334454/how-to-send-sms-from-an-iphone-app-without-opening-the-sms-interface)

Answer (score 4):

Again the reason "HOW COULD THIS BE" is because Auto SMS only got away with it until Apple found out they were using their native process and now are banned from itunes. GG.

Answer (score 2):

Some results from testing...confirms this app is sending normal SMS WITHOUT user interaction!

1. WLAN ON + GSM OFF (no reception) => the app does NOT send SMS, even after reception is back no SMS gets send. In the phone's messages log it tells "failed sending SMS"
2. WLAN OFF + GSM ON => the app sends SMS without user interaction (I checked my bill, and in fact a SMS got sent through the provider! - no data traffic to a server!)

So somehow this app sends a real SMS without user confirmation.

How could this be?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send SMS without user acceptance. I don't know about `Auto SMS` but there are a lot of web-services in internet which can send SMS. I guess some app uses those services or uses own. But Note: nothing is free there, should pay for everything

Comment: No, I tested, this app don't use a web-services.

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely scheduling SMS's to be sent on a server, and have integrated with a third party SMS service.

Comment: No, I tested, this app don't use a web-services.

Comment: @hungbm06 how did you come to know they don't use webservices ?

Comment: I turn off network of device and test this app. The sms still send normally.

Comment: The queued ones send even without network access? It may be that the app queues them and sends them to the server when you turn network back on.

Comment: i am agree with Lee and if you check the itune information they clearly mentioned that **n order to send out the scheduled message:

1) this app must be running on your iPhone, either in the background or in the foreground;
2) your iPhone must not be in the airplane mode;
3) your iPhone must have carrier's signal at the scheduled time** please check the info at the itune store for the app link you provided

Comment: please check this blog - http://gvexts.appspot.com/sms/sms.html

Answer (score 0):

TexTpressIt uses a server but also offers automatic scheduling of emails. The SMS function works. AutoSMS was recently banned because Apple DOESN't ALLOW an interface with their SMS native to the iPhone. TexTpressIt seems to be the only one worthwhile available on iPad as well as iTouch and iPhone, but it does more than just SMS messaging.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scheduling of sms and other features like that, than you can use [Trumpia](http://trumpia.com/) api. for that you have to create an API Key under your reseller account.Once the key is given the document should be self explanatory.