# Directly send sms from app by clicking button in app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on application. I want to send sms to number directly by clicking button in my app. currently my app is sending sms to number but it first shows the messages view and then there is a send button as i've done:
   presentModalViewController:controller
i want the message to be sent without showing the Modal view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send SMS from an iPhone app without opening the SMS interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334454/how-to-send-sms-from-an-iphone-app-without-opening-the-sms-interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't this is not allowed.
This way you could send hunders or thousands of messages without the user noticing, thus apple does not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You have to show the user de message view where he can send the sms. If it would be possible to add a 'send sms' function directly to a button, that would be a huge security flaw!

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no official way on iOS to send a message without presenting the dialog and the user clicking send. Maybe on a jailbroken device you could, but definitely not on the app store.