# How to know iphone auto sending sms?

Tags: iphone, sms

programmatically send SMS on the iPhone with out show `MFMessageComposeViewController`? It's possible? b/c I want to konw when's my phone send sms. I don't want my phone auto sending SMS. 
If it's possible, how to know? How to catch that event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send SMS from an iPhone app without opening the SMS interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334454/how-to-send-sms-from-an-iphone-app-without-opening-the-sms-interface)

Answer (score 1):

In theory (and assuming the phone is not jailbroken), you cannot send an SMS without user intervention. If sending SMS messages via the API, the user will see the message-compose view controller.

That said, I suppose an app could "bypass" this by sending an HTML request to a third-party SMS gateway (in other words, the iphone is not actually sending the text message, but an external server is).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not using the SMS capability provided by the phone. An app author wanting to send SMS without the usual UI would have to purchase capacity from some third party provider (search for 'SMS provider' to find many such providers). Messages sent that way would cost the app developer money, which is as powerful a disincentive as you can find. They also wouldn't be identified with you.